# Autoit - Compare each element of two arrays

Tags: arrays, compare, autoit

I'm attempting to compare two arrays. One array would be the pixels read of a row on a character of text (to ID) being 1 for color of text and 0 for being not text. The second array would have a key. A series of if statements will id this and i'm wondering firstly about the comparison of arrays!  If you have any helpful ideas please let me know!

I've checked all around online and found similar questions with answers that didn't seem to work in my case   :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare arrays this way:

```
#include <Array.au3>

    For $i = 0 To UBound($Array1)-1
        $found = _ArraySearch($Array2, $Array1[$i])
        ConsoleWrite("Array1[" & $i & "] = Array2[" & $found & "] : " & $Array1[$i] & "=" & $Array2[$found] & @LF)
    Next
```